# $f\in C^2[-1,1]\text{ then }\exists \xi\in(-1,1)\text { such that }\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x)\mathrm dx=2f(0)+\frac15f''(\xi)$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I am trying to solve the following problem :

$f\in C^2[-1,1]\text{ then }\exists \xi\in(-1,1)\text { such that }\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x)\mathrm dx=2f(0)+\frac15f''(\xi)\tag*{*}$

If we write $$f(x)=f(0)+xf'(0)+\frac{x^2}2f''(\zeta)\text{ for some }\zeta\in(-1,1)$$

then $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1 x^2f(x)\mathrm dx=\frac23f(0)+\frac15f''(\zeta)$

But I can't able to find the form of $(*)$

I've also tried expanding $x^2f(x)$ around $0$:

$$x^2f(x)=\left.x^2f(x)\right|_{x=0}+x\cdot\left.(x^2f(x))'\right|_{x=0}+\frac{x^2}2\cdot\left.(x^2f(x))''\right|_{x=\zeta},\text{ for some }\zeta\in(-1,1)$$

but this doesn't lead to $(*)$

So my question is how to proceed with this problem.

Comment: How about integrating by parts and trying to use the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conclusion is not always true. Consider the function $f(x)=1, \forall x\in [-1,1]$.
We have $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1x^2f(x)dx=\int_{-1}^1x^2dx=\frac{2}{3}$ and $\displaystyle 2f(0)+\frac{1}{5}f''(\xi)=2$ for any $\xi\in (-1,1)$